# Diagnosing Windows 10 Explorer stalls, if ProcMon prevents the stalls from occurring

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, freeze

I have been suffering from 30+ second File Explorer stalls when I open a new window as well as similar stalls when I open an Open File or Save File dialog from certain Windows 10 programs for a few months now.
The stalls aren't entirely consistent, but are a serious productivity issue when they are occurring.

I took steps to clear the File Explorer cache, disable Quick Access, and various other recommendations, with no luck.

After that, I took the recommendation to look into the issue with Process Monitor (ProcMon) and made the very odd discovery that as long as ProcMon64.exe is running, the stalls stop occurring. After I close ProcMon, this effect seems to stick around for a little while (maybe as much as a minute), and then the stalls return.

While it is interesting that ProcMon "solves" my stalls, it is ugly and a bit impractical to try to leave it running all the time to get rid of the stalls (particularly as ProcMon reliably crashes in about an hour). And it's a deep annoyance that this has made it impossible to investigate why the stalls are occurring so that I can track down whether there's a background program, service, or plugin involved.

Does anyone know of an alternate way to investigate, or else have any idea why starting ProcMon would prevent stalls from occurring?

Comment: Open Control Panel, Security and Maintenance and look at Reliability History. Do you have a string of "Windows Explorer or Windows Stopped working errors"?

Comment: Can you run `procdump -ma explorer.exe` (Sysinternals tool) to create a dump when in this state? If so I would then install WinDbg from the Windows SDK, ensure symbols are configured for Microsoft.  Then I would suggest getting the MEX debugging extension from Microsoft - Google that..  Load that in WinDbg with `.load mex.dll`.  Then type `!mex.p` Then click through to the Unique stacks.  I would suggest that there will be a stack that sticks out, probably length that would suggest what the process is doing.

Comment: No Reliability History issues. The problem doesn't result in an explorer crash, only a 30-45 second freeze.

Answer (score 0):

As an update, it turned out that while having ProcMon usually caused the stalls not to occur, I left it running (and restarted it whenever it crashed) all day, and eventually one of the stalls occurred with it enabled.

This allowed me to track down the cause to a plugin which created a drive mapping (to my P: drive) that has no ability to support files at the root (in P:/) because it fakes a bunch of non-windows network target file systems as sub-directories (i.e. as "P:/<target_ip>/").

It turns out that some windows functionality (perhaps search indexing or logging?) is trying to create files in P:/, and that file creation operation was taking 30-45 seconds to time out and fail.

Disabling the 3rd party plugin is a temporary fix, but not ideal, as I do need access to the non-windows remote file systems to do my job in some cases, and installing and removing the plugin all the time is messy. So I'll be hunting around for some way to exclude the P: drive from whatever windows 10 functionality is trying to create a file at the root, and perhaps contacting the plugin developer if there's some need to modify the plugin to prevent windows from treating the P: drive as a real drive.

In case anyone is better at reading ProcMon log entries, these are examples of what I saw (where the second column is duration):

```
11:38:18.6641941 AM   61.9618572        Explorer.EXE      8364      CreateFile              P:\         SUCCESS             Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
11:39:21.2780279 AM   29.3647640        Explorer.EXE      8364      CreateFile              P:\         0xC000022D      Desired Access: Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a
```

Comment: Have a look at the stack for the createfile operations. Configuring symbols will help.